# jquery sliding menu not working with IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle, slideup

All other browsers (including IE8+) seem to handle this code with no issue; just IE7 is failing. It does nothing when the li is clicked (no console errors either). Using latest jquery 1.7.2 library.

Here is the javascript function:

```
function expandableMenu(){
    $('#nav li').click(function(){
        var $child = $(this).next();
        if($child.is('.subNav')){
            if($child.is(':hidden')){
                $('#nav > ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $child.slideToggle(300);
        }
    });
}
```

here's the html:

```
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="accommodations"></li>
    <ul class="subNav">
      <li><a href="#">Kitchen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Family Room</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sauna</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li id="attractions"></li>
    <ul class="subNav">
      <li><a href="#">Bryce Canyon National Park</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Zion National Park</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cedar Breaks Natl Monument</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li id="reserve"></li>
  </ul>
```

finally, the CSS:

```
#nav {
    top: -40px;
    left: 6px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

#nav li {
    height: 39px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
}

#nav ul.subNav {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 273px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're using nested lists you have to put second `ul` inside `li` element:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="accommodations">First list
        <ul class="subNav">
          <li><a href="#">Kitchen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Family Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sauna</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="attractions">Second list
        <ul class="subNav">
          <li><a href="#">Bryce Canyon National Park</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Zion National Park</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cedar Breaks Natl Monument</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="reserve"></li>
</ul>
```

Then use `var $child = $(this).find('.subNav');` to get nested list in your `click` event. Try changing `z-index`, when I was checking your code on jsfiddle clicking did nothing too - when I changed `-1` to `99` it started work. Maybe IE7 does not recognize negative `z-index` values.

Comment: Thanks Wirone. Any suggestions on re-writing the javascript? Because I now have them nested, the selectors become different which is causing me issues. The underlying ul opens, but the remaining menu does not slide; the underlying subNav just opens beneath the menu.

Comment: Please update your html structure with one you're using now so I can work on javascript. Now your selector is `#nav > ul` which searches for ul directly in `#nav` (and it's not there), I think you should use `$('#nav ul.subNav').not($child).slideUp(300);` to hide previously opened submenus and then toggle `$child`'s visibility.

Comment: after tweaking some CSS, I finally got it working. I will post my final solution later tonight. Thanks for your help.